# Sub query in linq to sql

Tags: linq, t-sql, subquery

I want to return the comma seperated of the sub query result in my sql command. 
As follow:

```
Select  [User].UserName,
    (Select [Role].Name + ', '
            From
            Security.UserRole       As  UserRole
                Inner Join
            Security.[Role]         As  [Role]
                On  UserRole.RoleId =   [Role].RoleId

            Where   UserRole.UserId =   [User].UserId
            For Xml Path('')
    )
    From    Security.[User]         As  [User]
```

Basically each user has multiple roles, and I want to load the roles names in comma separated format for each user.

The result set in Sql is like  :
[image]

Is there any way I can write this query in LINQ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Code

Create a Method Get User roles Particular User

```
Public String GetuserRoles(int userid)
{
  string strroles="";
        (from UserRole in Security.UserRole 
             join Role in Security.Role on UserRole.RoleId  equals Role.RoleId
            where UserRole.UserId==userid
             select new
             {
                 strs = Role.Name + ","
             }).ToList().ForEach(c => strroles = strroles + c.strs);

     return strroles;
}
```

After Write  Your Linq Query:

```
 var result=( from p in  Security.User  select new {
              UserName=p.UserName,
              Roles=GetuserRoles(p.UserId)
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, The problem is I need to use it in odata method, So it should be IQueriable. So it should all be in single query.

Comment: how to possible single query? pls Write  the Query